# Has anyone experienced Excel Paste-special corrupting data in Tables? (Using 16.0 for Win32)

Tags: excel, corruption

I have been chasing my tail for half a day with a complex spreadsheet that is REFUSING to behave politely! I am actually trying to fix a problem experienced by another user on a different system, so it is not just me imagining things.

In short, selecting a column of data after a formula edit (to append a character to the previous string, via a holding column) when I do a "simple" paste-in-place, values only, Excel is shifting A2 to A1, A3 to A2 etc, and losing the last value altogether.
[Update: I have realised that is not even attempting to paste the new data to the destination range. It is just bumping the content of the destination column up one cell, losing the old top value entirely, leaving a blank at the bottom, and doing nothing with the copied data at all.]

[Example "Drop zone" before copy & paste](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sheMU.png)

[Drop zone after "pasting" the copied data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kjmSw.png)

Notes: copied data in the example is a 9x1 range, all values without the terminal 'A'.  In the target zone, after the "paste" NO new data are present, the top value, beginning BY has been lost entirely, and the bottom value of the paste range is a copy of the cell value below, outside the paste range, beginning CP.

Sorry I cannot show the "copied" data, I don't have enough 'reputation' points to add a third screen cap!

[Truly UGLY workaround... resize the table to exclude the drop zone. Paste as normal, then reassign the table size. Even after doing this, the same problem persists if I try copy and pasting more data to another part of the table.]

It is ONLY doing this in the context of a Table. Outside the table, behaviour is normal.

This is way beyond the normal scope of minor irritation with Excel, it is monstrous! Recreating the project, even the just the specific table, is hardly a realistic option.

Any ideas what can have caused it to get so bent out of shape? And how to force it to come to its senses?

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling your Excel and then attempt to replicate the same problem?

Comment: I have not. What I have done is look at it under Excel Mac, instead of Excel Windows (in Parallels). From a certain revision point a couple of days ago, any subsequent version opened on the Mac throws an "unsupported content" error at me, even though I added nothing out of the ordinary that I can think of. But even winding the clock back to that point with Excel Win is creating the same paste error...

Comment: Would be nice to see a screen shot of the before and after as I am not sure I completely understand the question.

Comment: Besides, my colleague in Europe was the first one to experience the problem, and she is not using my computer ;-)